# Express : Shouldn't middleware stop being called once a response is made?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this issue where **inside a router file that returns a router object - middleware is getting called after a response is already made.**

I thought middleware placed after a route will never get executed
for that route, I especially thought that would be true if a response
was already given.

**Main question:**

**Middleware should stop being called after the response right?**

Ex: When calling the endpoint "/login" and sending a response
    both middleware A and B are called.

Note: I have wrapped the router in a higher order function
(for socket.io functionality but that is beside the point).

Code Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var wrappedRouter = function(val) {

    router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Inside login route");
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('login.html'))
    }

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Exectuing middleware A");
    });

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Exectuing middleware B");
    });

    router.get('/another-route', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('login.html'))
    }

    return router;

}
//Prints:
// Inside login route
// Exectuing middleware A
// Exectuing middleware B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is absolutely correct, if you do not call next, next middleware in chain will never get executed, The problem you are facing is because, as you have already guessed, due to static resources your page is requesting, like favicon or images or anything else (separate requests). To get concrete proof, you can log url while serving express requests and see what requests are made and what gets executed using `req.url` as shown below

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var wrappedRouter = function(val) {
    router.get('/login', function(req, res) { 
        console.log("Inside login route: " + req.url);
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('login.html'))
    });

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Exectuing middleware A: "  + req.url);
    });

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Exectuing middleware B: "  + req.url);
    });

    router.get('/another-route', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('login.html'))
    });

    return router;
}

module.exports = wrappedRouter({});
```

Notice `req.url` in `console.log("Inside login route: " + req.url);` this will append current req resource and we'll be able to identify whats called and why. As shown below

[image: Diagnostics]

So now we know whats happening and why, now lets see how we can resolve it.

In express the order in which we register stuff to express app is very important. And I'd suggest registering your middleware separately (first) and then register your routes, this will increase the manageability of your super awesome code!

That being said, coming to the problem at hand, as sequence matters, what is happening in your case it, express tries each and every middleware in sequence and until it runs out of it. So, when server asks for 'favicon' (or some other static resource), it starts executing matching middleware in sequence. "Middleware A" handles the request and generates the output (keep in mind that the favicon is not served, actually nothing happens and the request will keep on handing until you call next or send something in response.

The solution to your problem is registering a static folder in the beginning of your app.js, before anything gets registered. This way when static resources are requested, they are served right away, and other requests which are not entertained by static resource middleware are passed on to your middleware.

It is not advisable to serve files are you are doing, as the app grows you may find it hard to manage, instead you should use view engines / static middleware to get what you are trying to achieve, as shown in below code.

Your app structure should be as follows, and it will resolve your issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//This will return wrapped routers
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var other = require('./routes/other');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//Just after registering all request parsing middleware, register static middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/others', other);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

If you are new to express and want to get started and see what works how, I have written a small blog about it, Part one is done, rest are in queue ;)

[Get started with Express and build RESTful api](https://oddcode.daveamit.com/2015/12/06/restful-api-with-express-js-and-mongodb-part-1/)
In this part, I show how to scaffold an express app, above code from it. You might find it helpful.

Hope it helps! Please let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Great Answer! I realize now that the big gap in my understanding was I thought that the statics were found with the first request and sent along with the html. From what I understand now -the html will be sent first and the links from the html make separate requests for the static resources using href. I believe since some statics weren't found (like favicon) the program was running through loose middleware in my router object file(index.js), which made it appear like the middleware was running past where it should. thx to everyone who pitched in to leading to an answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Be awesome and continue writing awesome code!

Answer (score 1):

Express is executing middleware in same order that you defined it and lifecycle does not end with `res.send()`.

You can use them e.g. to postprocess even when request was already satisfied.

```
var wrappedRouter = function(val) {
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        request.startProcessingTime = +(new Date());
        next();
    });

    router.get('/another-route', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('login.html'))
    }

    (...)
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        req.endProcessingTime = +(new Date());
        next();
    });

    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('Processing time:', req.endProcessingTime - req.startProcessingTime)
    });

    return router;

}
```

Comment: If that's true, this article -https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/  - totally lead me astray(Look under "MiddleWare Pitfalls" subheader "Order Matters").

Comment: Also, I thought if ```next()``` wasn't called then the next middleware process wouldn't be called.

Comment: @NickPineda yes, I've added to sample.

Comment: I was referring to my own - Middleware A and B are placed after and the handler for "/login" - but they still get called. :/

Comment: Wasn't that browser call for other thing as eg favicon or something ?

Comment: I believe there was a call for the eg.favicon - Do you think it was calling that middleware?

Comment: It could be because that router object was imported like so ```app.use('/', index);``` so maybe a call to a favicon was all being passed to that router

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I should say, please make sure the `next()` is called in the `router.use()` as below.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Exectuing middleware A");
    next();
});

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Exectuing middleware B");
    next();
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Inside login route");
    res.send('Hello World');
});
```

Which output

```
Exectuing middleware A
Exectuing middleware B
Inside login route
```

If the `next()` does not invoked in the `router.use()`

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Exectuing middleware A");
    //next();
});

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Exectuing middleware B");
    //next();
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Inside login route");
    res.send('Hello World');
});
```

Output:

```
Exectuing middleware A
```

And the response is pending in the browser for this request...

Comment: That's what doesn't make sense from my example because the "/login" path responds and doesn't call ```next()``` - yet Middleware A and B are still called even though they placed after the "/login" handler.

Comment: @NickPineda, I just test the codes shown in my answer, maybe other codes in your project affect it. BTW, the `router.use(` without path in it,  all requests to this router will first hit this middleware

Comment: @NickPineda, more details please read this [doc](router.use([path], [function, ...] function)), the `router.use([path], [function, ...] function)` part.

Comment: Do you think it was could be caused by the favicon like in the discussion mentioned in @Damian 's answer?

Comment: @NickPineda, maybe it is the cause, you can use [fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software)) to watch the HTTP package for more details.